# How do I adjust the maximum message size for a BrokeredMessage in Windows Server Service Bus?

Tags: c#, .net, servicebus, windows-server

I've set up Windows Server Service Bus 1.0 on a VM running Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter.

I've written a console application to send and receive messages to and from it and this works well.

I've been sending messages of increasing size successfully but the console app currently falls over when getting to 5,226,338 bytes (5,226,154 bytes message body + 184 bytes header I believe) which is just under 5MB.  Ideally we need a bit more room to play with.

Some of the stack trace is as below...

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException: The
>   socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:01:09.2720000'. - -->
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was
>   aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a
>   receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying
>   network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:01:09.2720000'.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: The write operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket
>   connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing
>   your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host,
>   or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was
>   '00:01:09.2720000' . ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine

The Windows Azure Service Bus apparently has a fixed limit of 256KB but the on premise Windows Server Service Bus has a limit of 50MB.  See the articles below.

Mention of the Azure limit of 256KB - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694235.aspx

Mention of 50MB - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193026.aspx

I'm struggling to achieve the 50MB limit and would like to know if there is something I need to do to configure this somehow or perhaps the message needs to be sent in a certain way.  I noticed there was a parameter name in the above article and wondered if that could be used in PowerShell.

I've struggled to find some good information on this online.  There is much confusion out there with some articles relating to Azure Service Bus but others relating to Windows Server Service Bus.

There is Service Bus 1.1 but I think this is in preview at the moment and I'm not sure this will help.

I am using code similar to the below to send the message.

namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.Create();
messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create();

queueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(queueName);

queueClient.Send(new BrokeredMessage(new string('x', 5226154)));

This was taken from a combination of the articles below, the first one being slightly outdated and second one making it slightly clearer what needed to be changed in order to get things working.

http://haishibai.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/walkthrough-setting-up-development.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj218335(v=azure.10).aspx

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same problem but I have figured it out after few tries.

Just open file

```
C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.1\Microsoft.ServiceBus.Gateway.exe.config
```

and change nettcp binding with name `netMessagingProtocolHead` set

```
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
maxBufferSize="2147483647"
```

and restart all service bus services.

Now I'am able to send and receive message with size `new string('A', 49 * 1024 * 1024)`.

Enjoy :-)

Martin

Comment: Thanks @Martin.  That has certainly helped and we are now successfully sending messages in excess of 49MB which should be more than adequate for our needs.  We are hitting problems when approaching message sizes of 50MB during testing but I suspect this is related to the extra information that gets sent with the body.

Comment: For the interest of others, the services I restarted in order for the changes to take effect were Service Bus Gateway and Service Bus Message Broker.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you're getting is a timeout, so your best bet is probably to fine tune your timeouts a little bit. Have you tried setting the client side timeout to a higher value? You can do that via the [MessagingFactorySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingfactorysettings.aspx) object. Also, have you checked the server side logs to see if anything there gives you a clue?

The parameter you mention is to set a quota. When you send a message that it's bigger than the quota it should be immediately rejected. In your case, the message is being accepted, but it is apparently timing out when in transit.

Comment: This sounds like it could be useful.  Do you have an example of the code or a suitable link?  I'm successfully creating the MessagingFactorySettings object and passing it in to the constructor but it either doesn't like the way I am constructing the address / URI or it doesn't like the TokenProvider I seem to have to specify.  It seems to be expecting the URI to relate to Windows Azure in some instances.

It might be worth me mentioning, when there is a failure it's instant rather than appearing to delay before timing out.  A successful message send will take a second or two to send.

Comment: FYI @Ramiro, in this case it did not appear to be a timeout issue.